# Can I set up a TPM2 policy that ANDs multiple OR policies?

Tags: tpm

I'd like to define a TPM access policy that allowlists multiple different values for certain PCRs. Hence, i'd like a policy like this:

```
(PolicyOR(PolicyPCR(value1,pcr4),PolicyPCR(value2,pcr4),PolicyPCR(value3,pcr4)) AND PolicyOR(PolicyPCR(value4,pcr7),PolicyPCR(value5,pcr7)) AND
PolicyOR(PolicyPCR(value6,pcr9),PolicyPCR(value7,pcr9)))
```

Or in other words: I want to list three different allowed hash values for PCR4, 2 values for PCR 7, and another two values for PCR 9.

Does TPM2 allow policy expressions like this? How would I fulfill them?

the part I don't get: let's say I pick the first option on each PCR, i.e. value1 on pcr4, value4 or pcr7 and value6 on pcr9. I can start with submitting PolicyPCR(value1,pcr4) to the TPM. Then I can submit PolicyOR to it, with hashes of the three branches. Good so far. But what do I do next? I'd need to start at zero now, for the second AND term, but I don#t want to lose the policy state I already set up. So how does this work? Does this work at all?

Answer (score 1):

That is possible. Each policy assertion (using a `TPM2_Policy...` command) *extends* the existing policyDigest hash. Therefore, if you just chain policies, you archive a logical AND of these policies (in that exact order). Initially, policyDigest starts at `0x00..00`. [1](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG_TPM2_r1p59_Part1_Architecture_pub.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A564%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C69%2C314%2C0%5D)

[image: policyDigest_new = Hash(policyDigest_old||policyAssertion]

PolicyAssertion is the result of a policy in the form of a hash. E.g. the PolicyAssertion of PolicyOr (which includes three PolicyPCRs) is as follows. D0, D1 and D2 you will probably have to pre-calculate on host side.

[image: policyAssertion_{PolicyOR}:=Hash(D_0 || D_1 || D_2 )]

[image: D_0 = Hash(\mathrm{0x00...00} || PolicyAssertion_{PolicyPCR_A})]
[image: D_1 = Hash(\mathrm{0x00...00} || PolicyAssertion_{PolicyPCR_B})]
[image: D_2 = Hash(\mathrm{0x00...00} || PolicyAssertion_{PolicyPCR_C})]

The end result of all your policies is a single hash value `policyDigest` which is stored in the `authPolicy` of the TPM entity to be access controlled.

When you want to access your TPM entity, you start a session (`TPM2_StartAuthSession`) and call the different `TPM2_Policy...` commands. Each policy command changes the `policyDigest` of your session. If you can archive that the `policyDigest` of the session is equal to the `authPolicy` of the entity, you can access the entity.